# CakePHP Auth: redirecting unauthorized users

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp

I'm new to CakePHP and i'm setting up an Acl controlled app. What I want to do is if the user isn't logged in yet no matter where he tries to go he gets redirected to the login action, how would I manage to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it by setting up the [AuthComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html), which does exactly that.

Auth handles the login, ACL handles the access rights.

Comment: Thank you, deceze. So in each controller I just add the beforeFilter() with the actions I want public and that makes them public as I can see, but how do I redirect to the login screen if they try to access private controllers/actions?

Comment: @8vius That's exactly what the AuthComponent does for you in its default configuration.

Comment: It's not working for me that way, whenver I try to access i get a redirect loop error on my browser if

Comment: @8vius Please update your question and show how you set up the AuthComponent.

Comment: Thanks for the help deceze I also dug a little further and set up admin routing for my app

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in your controller

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
    'loginAction' => array(
          'controller' => 'users','action' => 'login'
         ),
     'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?'
 );
}
```